# How to output the sips image in directory

Tags: shell, sips

```
sips --resampleWidth 300 --out ./changedPic/A.png ./Normal/A.png
```

I did this command in shell.

however it didn't make the A.png under changedPic directory but made 'changedPic' file.

It's not normal behavior of shell script though,,, How can I make A.png under changePic??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the directory first if it doesn't exist:

```
mkdir -p ./changedPic; sips --resampleWidth 300 --out ./changedPic/A.png ./Normal/A.png
```

Use the `-p` option to ignore the error if the directory already exists.